# Terminal is energetically expensive

Tags: terminal, mac

Checking the activity monitor, I've noticed that one of my most expensive apps (energy-wise) is the Terminal. It's marked as "requires heavy GPU performance".

Why, and what can I do to improve the situation?

Comment: What is running in Terminal?

Comment: @patrix nodeJS +ember-cli. While possibly cpu-intensive, it's the "GPU" part that lets me perplexed.